# Как вывести дату регистрации пользвателя wordpress во внешнем интерфейсе

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как для внешнего интерфейса вывести дату регистрации пользователя?
Есть страница автора, там вывел базовую информацию, но не могу вывести дату когда человек был зарегистрирован на сайте.
Все коды пробовал, интернет облазил - выводит или сегодняшную дату, или *01.01.1970*.
И это когда вошёл под амдинкой, а надо чтоб просто гости могли гулять по сайту и смотреть когда авторы были зарегистрированы на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться функцией [get_userdata()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_userdata). Если это страница автора, то это может выглядеть таким образом:

```
$user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

$register_date = $user_info->user_registered;
echo esc_html__('Registration date: ', 'textdomain') . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($register_date));
```

Здесь при помощи функции [get_the_author_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_author_meta) Вы можете получить ID автора. Далее получаете саму дату `$user_info->user_registered` из объекта и конвертируете в удобный Вам вид при помощи функции [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php), форматы дат можно посмотреть [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php).

---

Если речь о плагине [UsersWP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/userswp/), что выяснилось по итогу, то Вы можете переписать существующий шаблон, согласно [документации](https://docs.userswp.io/article/680-how-to-override-templates-for-userswp), но конкретно в Вашем случае код может выглядеть так (так как у Вас уже существует определенный шаблон):

```
<?php $registration_date = uwp_get_displayed_user()->user_registered ?? ''; ?>
<div class="since"><?php esc_html_e('На проекте с', 'textdomain'); ?> <?php echo $registration_date ? date('F j, Y', strtotime($registration_date)) : ''; ?></div>
```

При помощи функции `uwp_get_displayed_user()` Вы можете получить объект пользователя, на странице профиля которого Вы находитесь и работать с ним в дальнейшем.

---

**UPD**: если нужно чтобы дата выводилась согласно локализации Вашего сайта, то можно сделать таким образом с использованием [date_i18n()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/date_i18n):

```
<?php $registration_date = uwp_get_displayed_user()->user_registered ?? ''; ?>
<div class="since"><?php esc_html_e('На проекте с', 'textdomain'); ?> <?php echo $registration_date ? date_i18n('F j, Y', strtotime($registration_date)) : ''; ?></div>
```

Comment: Только что попробовал ваш код и вот что он показывает: Notice: Trying to get property 'user_registered' of non-object in /var/www

Comment: Может там какойто цыкл должен быть?

Comment: А каким образом выглядит страница автора, это файл `author.php`? И сделайте `var_dump(get_the_author_meta('ID'));`, что показывает?

Comment: string(0) ""   Вот это

Comment: А название шаблона? И если не сложно, добавьте его содержание в вопрос.

Comment: <?php
 /*
 * Template Name: Страница автора
 */

get_header(); ?> 

  </head>
  <body>
  
 
<div class="main">  
 
    <?php get_search_form(); ?> <div class="since">На проекте с <?php  var_dump(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?><?php $registered = ($user_info->user_registered . "\n");
  echo date("j M Y", strtotime($registered));  ?></div>

Comment: у меня прмо не открывается страница author.php потому что стоит плагин UsersWP который автоматически создает страницы с шорткодам, потипу, учетная запись, страница, войти, страница забыли пароль, и тд
но я сделалпод учетную запись как шаблон страницы и просто убрал отуда <?php the_content() ?>

Comment: @Dmutro_s90_Lexusukrnet с этого и следовало начинать, конечно же это не будет работать в таком виде. Каким шорткодом Вы пользуетесь для вывода информации автора, какая информация выводится сейчас? Код лучше добавлять в сам вопрос, а не комментарием, так как он в таком случае не читаем. `the_content()` убирать не стоит, иначе как и куда Вы добавите шорткод? Просто как шаблон страницы, без шорткода, выводить ничего не будет, так как каким образом вообще будет понятно что это должен быть шаблон автора?

Comment: Если у вас есть время то я могу вам предоставвить доступ в адмику и вы за минуту все поймете! что и как работает

Comment: отправил на почту!